# How to convert manipulated data from .fits file to pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, astropy, fits

I have a .fits file with some data, from which I have made some manipulations and would like to store the new data (not the entire .fits file) as a pd.DataFrame. The data comes from a file called pabdatazcut.fits.

```
#Sorted by descending Paschen Beta flux
sortedpab = sorted(pabdatazcut[1].data , key = lambda data: data['PAB_FLUX'] , reverse = True )

unsorteddf = pd.DataFrame(pabdatazcut[1].data)

sortedpabdf = pd.DataFrame({'FIELD' : sortedpab['FIELD'],
                        'ID' :  sortedpab['ID'],
                        'Z_50' : sortedpab['Z_50'],
                        'Z_ERR' : ((sortedpab['Z_84'] - sortedpab['Z_50']) + (sortedpab['Z_50'] - sortedpab['Z_16'])) / (2 * sortedpab['Z_50']),
                        '$\lambda Pa\beta$' : 12820 * (1 + sortedpab['Z_50']),
                        '$Pa\beta$ FLUX' : sortedpab['PAB_FLUX'],
                        '$Pa\beta$ FLUX ERR' : sortedpab['PAB_FLUX_ERR']})
```

''''

I have received the 'TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str' error message when I try to run this.

Comment: If you want to sort a Numpy array, at least in simple cases, don't use the Python `sorted()` built-in because now you're converting from Numpy array to a plain Python `list`. That's why your field name indexing stops working (you can see this by running your code line-by-line and checking the object types); don't just treat your code as a black box! Instead you can use Numpy's built-in [sort](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.sort.html) method on arrays. You can use the `order` argument to sort by a specific field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this because of accesses like `sortedpab['ID']` I guess. According to the doc `sorted` returns a sorted list. Lists do not accept strings as `id` to access elements. They can only be accessed by integer positions or slices. That's what the error is trying to tell you.

Unfortunately I can't test this on my machine, because I don't have your data, but I guess, what you really want to do is something like this:

```
data_dict= dict()
for obj in sortedpab:
    for key in ['FIELD', 'ID', 'Z_50', 'Z_50', 'Z_ERR', 'Z_84', 'PAB_FLUX', 'PAB_FLUX_ERR']:
        data_dict.setdefault(key, list()).append(obj[key])

sortedpabdf = pd.DataFrame(data_dict)
# maybe you don't even need to create the data_dict but
# can pass the sortedpad directly to your data frame
# have you tried that already?
#
# then I would calculate the columns which are not just copied
# in the dataframe directly, as this is more convenient
# like this:
sortedpabdf['Z_ERR']= ((sortedpabdf['Z_84'] - sortedpabdf['Z_50']) + (sortedpabdf['Z_50'] - sortedpabdf['Z_16'])) / (2 * sortedpabdf['Z_50'])
sortedpabdf['$\lambda Pa\beta$']= 12820 * (1 + sortedpabdf['Z_50']),

sortedpabdf.rename({
        'PAB_FLUX': '$Pa\beta$ FLUX', 
        'PAB_FLUX_ERR': '$Pa\beta$ FLUX ERR'
    }, axis='columns', inplace=True)

cols_to_delete= [col for col in sortedpabdf.columns if col not in ['FIELD', 'ID', 'Z_50', 'Z_ERR', '$\lambda Pa\beta$', '$Pa\beta$ FLUX','$Pa\beta$ FLUX ERR'])
sortedpabdf.drop(cols_to_delete, axis='columns', inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I did try to pass the sortedpab directly into a dataframe but I received a bunch of error messages (little endian compiler type messages). I will try what you suggested.

Comment: Please post the actual errors. Do note that data is stored in big-endian order in FITS files, so when passing arrays from FITS files to code that can only operate on little-endian byte order you need to convert it.